# Could I use interactive proxy authentication with git-svn?

Tags: git, svn, proxy, git-svn, ntlm

I'm behind an authenticating proxy and need to access a remote SVN repo over https using `git svn`.

The proxy is defined in my `~/.subversion/servers` file.

When I start with `git svn fetch`, I get an error message:

> RA layer request failed: OPTIONS of 'http://url/to/repos/branches/experimental'

Ok. [No problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5430368/520162) Let's write down the credentials to `~/.subversion/servers` → everything works fine.

However, I'm a *little* bit uncomfortable having my domain credentials stored in a plain text file on my hard disk.

Are there other ways (**especially interactive ones**) to authenticate at my proxy when using `git svn` over https?

**Info:** The PC where this should be accomplished is in a Windows domain and authentication is done with NTLM.

Comment: if your pc joined domain, does your proxy server support Kerbose or NTLM authentication?

Comment: Good question. It's NTLM. Adding that to my question!

Comment: try http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/ ,It supports:stores user's credentials in config file or requests password from a console during the start time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if im not mistaken ntlmaps can also pull the login form windows itself as you have joind the domain, defenetly worth a try

anyway if that doused work you can make ntlmaps ask for a password on start time

[Ntmlaps website](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Currently, I'm on holiday, I'll check it as soon as I'm working in the domain again. But if `ntlmaps` keeps it's promises, this is what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: update: tested `ntlmaps` and it proves that this is exactly what I was searching for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can protect `~/.subversion/servers` file by making sure you're the only one (and root) who can access it.

```
% chmod 600 ~/.subversion/servers
```

Another way is to use http_proxy environment variable. But you cannot use @ (and some other shell special chars) in your password.

```
% export http_proxy=http://user:pass@proxy:port
```

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.apache.org/subversion/EncryptedPasswordStorage mentions alternatives to file storage of passwords on mac, pc, linux

Comment: what has this got to do with SVN? They're talking about the SVN server but I need it for an SNV client!

Comment: +1 as the link provided is actually useful, as it provides options for client-side safe caching of passwords.